# FileSystemDate VBA codes

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Test()
myURL = "http://sps.ap.emersonprocess.com/sg/pssops/svcops/APServicePortal/ChartTemplates/IBS-CCR-AP_Prod.xlsx"
Filename = "IBS-CCR-AP_Prod.xlsx"
myURL = Replace(myURL, "http:", "")
myURL = Replace(myURL, "/", "\")
MsgBox FileDateTime(myURL & Filename)

end Sub
```

Can you review my codes I just wanted to know the when "IBS-CCR-AP_Prod.xlsx" saved in a sharepoint drive, thats why I used FileDateTime but unfortunetly I had an error path not found. Thanks Big Regards

Comment: Try `\\sps.ap.emersonprocess.com\sg\pssops\svcops\APServicePortal\ChartTemplates\IBS-CCR-AP_Prod.xlsx`

Answer (score 2):

myURL already contains your filename, you needn't concatenate it, simply use

```
MsgBox FileDateTime(myURL)
```

Comment: If I remove the Filename at concatinate it's still an error on the path "myURL".

Comment: @EJ_all_the_way then try to open the value of `myUrl` with your windows explorer, if it's not possible then your link/path is not correct

Comment: @katz When it comes to Workbook.Open(myUrl) without Replacing any string it works in saving... but when I used the fileDateTime I'm having an error.

(Invalid procedure call or agurment)

Comment: There has got to be some other error if your error message goes like that. Check for typos, you may provide an undeclared mistyped argument, that evaluates to Empty. You may also choose to use Option Explicit http://goo.gl/Ns4vL8

Comment: I got it... @ignotus thanks for the fact that i need to used always Option Explicit.